terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
I have 2 classes. I want to pass this from constructor one class as a parameter to the constructor of another class.
I am aware that the error occurred because shared_from_this() is called before the IkArm object (this) is fully constructed. But I am unable to find out a way in which I an pass the node to the second class after executing the first class. Also I have gone through this question but the relationship of the classes used there is different.
The following is the code:
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

class IkSolver
{
    public:
        IkSolver(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node) : node_(node)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "2nd Constructor");                
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node_;
};

class IkArm : public rclcpp::Node
{
    public:
        IkArm() : Node("IkNode")
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "1st Constructor");
            
            obj1_ = std::make_shared<IkSolver>(shared_from_this());
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Back To 1st Constructor");
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<IkSolver> obj1_;
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<IkArm>());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}


I am getting the following error:
[INFO] [1720452645.004303274] [IkNode]: 1st Constructor
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_weak_ptr'
  what():  bad_weak_ptr
[ros2run]: Aborted


EDIT_1:
After making changes suggested by @Ahmed AEK The following error occurs:
error: could not convert ‘std::enable_shared_from_this<_Tp>::shared_from_this() [with _Tp = rclcpp::Node]()’ from ‘shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>’ to ‘shared_ptr<IkArm>’
   32 |             return shared_from_this();
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
      |                                    |
      |                                    shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node>


The updated code:
#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"

class IkSolver
{
    public:
        IkSolver(std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node) : node_(node)
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "2nd Constructor");                
        }

    private:
        std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> node_;
};

class IkArm : public rclcpp::Node
{
    public:
        IkArm() : Node("IkNode")
        {
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "1st Constructor");
            
            RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "Back To 1st Constructor");
        }

        std::shared_ptr<IkArm> init()
        {
            obj1_ = std::make_shared<IkSolver>(shared_from_this());
            return shared_from_this();
        }

    private:    
        std::shared_ptr<IkSolver> obj1_;
};


int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
    rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<IkArm>()->init());
    rclcpp::shutdown();
    return 0;
}


You simply cannot use shared_from_this inside the constructor. I usually think about ways to change the API, usually by means of a factory function to create the object and then do something with the shared_ptr, or by adapting the logic and the "who does what" to accomodate the shared_from_this.

Somewhat unrelated to the question at hand, but note that unless you take extra steps to prevent it (that aren't shown), your current code will result in a memory leak since an IkArm owns an IkSolver which in turn owns the IkArm.  Neither shared_ptr's ref count will ever reach 0 (and thus neither object will ever be deleted) as long as you have that cycle in your ownership graph.  std::weak_ptr may help in resolving that issue.

You cannot call shared_from_this from the constructor, you can only call shared_from_this on objects that are already bound to a shared_ptr, while std::make_shared binds an object to the shared_ptr after its constructor is complete.
from std::enable_shared_from_this

It is permitted to call shared_from_this only on a previously shared
object, i.e. on an object managed by std::shared_ptr. Otherwise,
std::bad_weak_ptr is thrown (by the shared_ptr constructor from a
default-constructed weak-this).

you need to put the construction of the member inside another member function that you call outside of the constructor.
rclcpp::spin(std::make_shared<IkArm>()->init());

// init implemenation
std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> IkArm::init()
{
    obj1_ = std::make_shared<IkSolver>(shared_from_this());
    return shared_from_this();
}

also note that you have a cyclic reference, you should only store a weak_ptr inside the member, not a shared_ptr otherwise neither of the two objects will be deleted.

Thanks for response. But i am getting another error. Have updated the question.

@Pratham just make the return type std::shared_ptr<rclcpp::Node> instead.

Thanks. The issue is resolved. Just for info, have you worked previously with rclcpp library (Related to Robotics ROS2)?
